# Importing data into Cytoscape with defined "meanings"

Tags: cytoscape

When importing data, you can specify the "meaning" of each column. Source, target, edge attribute, etc.

When I import a csv or excel doc, I want a way to automate that definition. I.e. the first column is always the key, second source, third target. Is there a way to do that within the spreadsheet or do I have to modify that every time?

Some background: I have a file on a server I want other people to grab and it will be refreshed every week. I wish for it to be as easy as a setup as possible.

This is for the desktop version of cytoscape.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do that using a command.  Take a look at the "network import file" command.  You can call this from either the RCy3 or py4cytoscape packages (or on the command line).  This command allows you to specify the file, the source, target, column types, etc., etc.  Do a "help network import file" in the command line and you'll get all of the help text.